# How would one use llm's to proofread OCR texts?

Tags: nlp, ocr

I had thought to use simple statistics, Markov chains and a list of common OCR errors to find unlikely words and characters and their most probable replacement, But even a simple llm should do a better job. Are there freely available tools that can do this without a great deal of programming or model building?